# PHP codeigniter - how to return to DB table after updating row

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I want my admin table view to reload after uses selects Edit, changes entry and selects Update Entry with the edits reflected in the revised table row.

The admin edit page is working fine, and I know the solve for redirecging the update to the table page is basic. Some light guidance would be much appreciated!

**Admin View:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Admin Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body background=http://wallpapercave.com/wp/ItmVuT6.jpg>


<div class="container">
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <center>
    <thead> 
        <tr style="font-size: 24; color: white;">
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th colspan="2">Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    </center>
    <tbody style="background-color: #F0F8FF;">  
        <?php 
        foreach($users as $u)
        {
            $class = "btn btn-primary";
            $button = "Approve";  
            ?>
        <tr style="font-size: 20;">
            <td><?php echo $u->first_name; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $u->last_name; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $u->email; ?></td>
            <td><a class="btn btn-success" href="<?php echo site_url('myform/edituser/' . $u->id); ?>">Edit</a></td>
            <td><a class="<?php echo $class;?>" href="/ci/index.php/myform/approve/?user_id=<?php echo $u->id;?>"><?php echo $button;?></a></td> 
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

**Admin Edit View:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Edit User Info</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body background=http://wallpapercave.com/wp/ItmVuT6.jpg>

<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <form action="" method="post">


<p><font color="black" font size='5'/><strong>Entry for ID </strong><strong>"<?php echo $id; ?>"</strong></font></p>

<font color="black" font size='5'/><strong>First Name  </strong></font><input type="text" name='first_name' value="<?php echo $first_name; ?>"?><br/>

<font color="black" font size='5'/><strong>Last Name  </strong></font><input type="text" name='last_name' value="<?php echo $last_name; ?>"/><br/>

<font color="black" font size='5'/><strong>Email </strong></font><input type="text" name='email' value="<?php echo $email; ?>"/><br/>
<br/>
<input type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="Update Entry">

</div>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Controller:**

```
<?php

class Myform extends CI_Controller{

  public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct(); 
  }

  public function index(){
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('user[first_name]', 'First Name', 'required'); 
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('user[last_name]', 'Last Name', 'required'); 
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('user[email]', 'Email Address', 'required|trim'); 

    $form['userValues'] = [
        'first_name' => $this->input->post('user[first_name]'),
        'last_name'  => $this->input->post('user[last_name]'),
        'email'      => $this->input->post('user[email]'),
        'id'         => $this->input->post('id'),
    ];   

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view('myform');
    }
    else
    {
        $user = $this->input->post('user');
        //$company = $this->input->post('company'); 
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($user);
        //print_r($company); 

        if ($this->input->post('id') !== '' && $this->input->post('id') !== NULL)
        {
            $this->db->where('id', (int) $this->input->post('id'));
            $this->db->update("User_Inputs", $user);
        }
        else
        {
            $this->db->insert("User_Inputs", $user);
        }
            //$this->db->insert("companies", $company);         
        redirect("/myform/successmessage");
    }
}

    public function successmessage(){
        $this->load->view('formsuccess');
    }          

  public function getDatabase(){
    $data['users'] = $this->db->get("User_Inputs")->result();
    $this->load->view('adminlogin', $data);

  }

public function approve(){
    $id = $this->input->get("user_id"); 
    $this->db->where("id", $id); 
  $data['user'] = $this->db->get("User_Inputs")->row();
    echo "<pre>"; 
  print_r($this->db->last_query()); 
    print_r($data);
    echo "<h1>". $data['user']->email."</h1>";  

    die();
}

public function edituser($user_id = NULL)
{
    $user_id = (int) $user_id;

    $data['user'] = $this->db
        ->where('id', $user_id)
        ->get("User_Inputs")
        ->row();

    $form['dbValue'] = [
        'first_name' => $data['user']->first_name,
        'last_name'  => $data['user']->last_name,
        'email'      => $data['user']->email,
        'id'         => $user_id
    ];

    $this->load->view('editfields', $data['user']);
  }
}
```

Comment: You are echoing in the middle of a controller. That is not right.  Your controller should check the post data, if valid, update table. Then get your page data, then show whatever view you need to show. You should never echo from a controller.

Comment: you mean in the`approve` function? that's there as part of my initial test of outputs. what about the `edituser` function?

Comment: `$this->db->last_query();`
is that you mean?

Comment: that seems right yes. any chance you can show how youd incorporate that?

Comment: @Kelvin any ideas?